# i want to paste same background in all of my illustrator layers

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, cs6

I have 200 layers in one of my Illustrator CS6 project. i want to add same background group in all layers and then run batch ai to jpg.

how exactly can i paste the same background in every layer with single click.

Comment: Why not just make a background layer and only change visibility?

Comment: i want to export batch. batch doesn't change visibility automatically.

Comment: Ok. Have you considered creating art boards from layers? That would solve your issue I think.